# React-final-form how is submit handled in the render of the form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Seems I can't get a grip on how [React-final-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-final-form) works.

There is a functional component with the following sections: 
At the top:

```
import {Form, Field} from "react-final-form";
```

Then in the return:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <Form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            render={ ({innerSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values}) => (
                <form onSubmit={innerSubmit}>
                   ( Bunch of Fields... )

                     <div className="buttons">
                        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
                            Save
                        </button>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={form.reset}
                            disabled={submitting || pristine}>
                            Reset
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )}
        />
   </Fragment>
)
```

So, the render is a function which passes an object. In that object, the first one is 'innerSubmit'.

How is innerSubmit connected to the 'handleSubmit'?

And what are these values in the object  (innerSubmit, form, submitting, pristine and values). The render function in React.dom (where render is coming from) has different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Please check [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-final-form#handlesubmit-syntheticeventhtmlformelement--void) carefully. It seems that handleSumbit is kind of author's naming convention and should be used as a prop in render. On the other hand yours 'innerSumbit' (I suppose it's a form-handling function?) should be passed to 'onSumbit' in Form.

Probably a good idea for you is to check react-final-form author's [yt tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoSzy-4mviQ&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Hi, author here. The prop in render is called `handleSubmit`, just as ladyk said. Here's an explanation for the on- and handle- prefixes from another lib I wrote. https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/faq/handlevson.md/

Comment: @Erik, I watched your video and it is excellent. Learned a lot and I'm integrating it with Semantic UI.